# Task list does not allow group by people picker column created later

Tags: 2010, list-view, task-list, grouping

We have a list created using task list template. Later on we added an Item content type to it and created an Action Owner column of type People Picker.

But when we tried to create a view group by Action Owner group, Action Owner did not appear in the drop down.

I am not able to understand why it is not there.

Please suggest how this could be resolved. My list is already live and do not want to create a new list. All i need to do is to create a list view grouped by Action Owner.

Answer (score 0):

If your people or picker column "Action Owner" having allow multiple values, then group by wont be possible